# Image click in C# WinForms Browser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, custom-events

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.Body.MouseDown += Body_MouseDown;
}

void Body_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{   
    switch (e.MouseButtonsPressed)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Left:
            HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
            if (element != null && "img".Equals(element.GetAttribute("type"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Image Was Clicked");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way?

Any & All Help Is Appreciated.

Comment: Well what does `doesn't seem to work.` mean.. have you stepped thru the code using the debugger..? can you state what your expected outcome should be..??

Comment: @DJKRAZE What I want is when I click on an image in the web  browser control it should show the message Image Was Clicked. However, when I click on an image nothing happens.

Comment: Is your code entering the `if` statement? You need to step through the code.

Comment: @houstguy how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not all images in html has the `type` attribute. So you must define such that your clickable image has. For example, I redacted your code:

Initialisation of the webBrowser (you can put it in the constructor of your WinForm):

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

Your procedure Body_MouseDown:

```
void Body_MouseDown(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
            {
                switch (e.MouseButtonsPressed)
        {

            case MouseButtons.Left:
                HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
                if (element != null)
                {
                    string s = element.Style;

                    if ((s != null) && (s.IndexOf(".png") != -1)) MessageBox.Show("Image Was Clicked");
                }
                break;
        }       
            }
```

If you click on the google logo you will get the message box you want. The point is that I use attribute Style of the `HtmlElement` and searching the substring ".png" in it. You can search for all formats you want: jpg, gif, bmp, or all together.
Good luck.